# How do I automate the file download dialog(IE, Selenium and python)?

Tags: python, python-3.x

I have automated every step, just need to handle the file download dialog from clicking the link. Please any help would be appreciated, also the simpler the better! (windows 7)

EDIT:

I find myself answering 95% of the questions I ask on SO, I honestly do not know what to make of this.
Anyways pywinauto https://github.com/pywinauto/pywinauto.

Comment: For simplicity I'd just use `urllib`'s `urlretrieve`

Comment: erm the site has so much js it's not possible to use requests.